# My attached image isn't shown. Old other images from another peoples also

Tags: support, images, imgur

My attached image isn't shown. Neither are older images from another people.

Example where I don't see the image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763927

Comment: Are you sure *.imgur.com is not blocked in your network?

Comment: @ALL Thanks for responses! I double check Network tab in Firefox Web console and found that `imgur.com` isn't loaded. New corporate proxy restriction...

Comment: Hm... Moderators work bad... After right 2nd suggestion people discuss something that interested only by them and close issue with wrong assumption. In any case  thanks for interest to problem, especially to **rene**!

Comment: @gavenkoa sorry for the off topic comments, will remove them now. Anyway what rene said is also mentioned in the linked post so the closure is justified. Cheers, and sorry again!

Comment: @ShadowWizard never mind, I always have in mind that this job done by volunteer